# Rewriting taxonomy term in exposed filter

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, theming

I have an exposed taxonomy term filter with values of "true" and "false".  I would like to simply rename the options to "yes" and "no".

I can't simply change the taxonomy tern name since I am importing the values from a XML file.

How would you suggest I do this?
Is there a simple CSS rewrite - changing true to yes, and false to no?
Is there a field theme function I should use?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you go in the .module file pertaining "true"/"false" and find the values t(true) and t(false)?  That can be a dirty fix, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `hook_form_alter` to alter the names displayed in the options.

An alternative and a bit more tricky way, is to create your own views_filter_handler for them term used in the view, and customize how the exposed filter form should look like. This is a good solution if you are creating many views and want a single place to do the alterations. See [How do I add dropdowns in Filter Criteria in Views module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6611/how-do-i-add-dropdowns-in-filter-criteria-in-views-module/6650#6650) for more info.